# multiple language support for customer portal sites in sfdc?

Tags: internationalization, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

We are currently using the Salesforce customer portal for our customer community.  Answers, Ideas & Knowledge objects are all embedded into VF pages.   We are now looking to localize our product into German and French and will need a community for those languages.  Has anyone done this before?  Did you create new communities for each language, or do you translate all the posts/ content in the language their prefered language?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Custom Labels?  search for "Custom Labels Overview" in SF online help.